# Print Quality of Latex Documents on Windows 10

Tags: printing

I use Overleaf to generate PDF files from latex. When looked on the screen, the fonts in the PDF are perfect, even when I zoom in and watch really closely. However, when I print out the document, I notice little imperfections. For example, the letters O and C are not very smooth, and the letter y is not completely black. In comparison, the printouts of Word and Powerpoint documents seem to have higher quality fonts. I am sure it has something to do with my setup, but just wonder what it is.

Comment: It sounds like you do not have the fonts installed make sure you have cm-super package installed in miktex or texlive

Comment: I just installed it and the quality of the print is day and night!!!. I still have questions. Why displaying the fonts on the screen seemed okay? And on Windows 10, how do I know if the system is picking up the fonts? Thanks.